# Why is this park in Athens hidden from view in Google (but not Bing)?

Tags: greece, athens, google-maps

I noticed a [purposely blurred area in Athens](https://www.google.com/maps/@37.9755403,23.7403325,819a,35y,61.97h/data=!3m1!1e3) in Google Maps:

[image]

It seems that this is a normal botanical park, I could not find anything sensitive there (which is the typical reason for such blurring).

The equivalent image from Bing does not show the blurring (the orientation is roughly rotated +90° relative to the first one)

[image]

Comment: Given that the blurred region spans part of a park, several buildings and a major road, I suspect that this is just an image processing glitch, not intentional censorship.

Comment: @lambshaanxy: I do not think so. Look at how the Kolonakiou place is neatly trimmed, and gets into the blurred part: https://www.google.com/maps/@37.9770475,23.7406497,255a,35y,61.97h/data=!3m1!1e3. The blurring also closely follows roads (and the weird part of the park)

Comment: Someone reported that part at Google for privacy concerns, but not at Bing.. I guess it is as simple as that.

Comment: Your second image is not only rotated but misses many of the houses that are blurred in the first one.

Comment: A plausible answer is that the headquarters of the Presidential Guard are located roughly at the center of the blurred area.  The entrance can be seen at [this spot on Street View](https://goo.gl/maps/BL292n1pwTJetzQP9).  But this is just speculation on my part, which is why this isn't an answer.  Plus, the blurred area is much larger than the headquarters themselves, which doesn't entirely make sense.

Comment: @BernhardDöbler: yes I know, I aimed at the museum which is common to both maps - it was just an illustration of the lack of blurring on Bing.

Comment: The Bing version says  GREEK PARLIAMENT which would certainly be considered sensitive enough.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This part of Athens includes the Presidential Mansion, the Prime Minister's Office and several embassies and other government buildings. For some reason the Greek government thought it is strategically important to censor them from the internet, even though in most other countries such places are seen clearly.

Answer (score 4):

I have noticed before that Google maps blurs places on request from (local) governments where others do not blur.

One explanation is that Google maps was earlier and the request for blurring was not repeated with the other mapping services.
An other explanation is that the other map services did not comply with the request.

And a third is that while the area was sensitive at one time, it is no longer and Google did not remove the blurring yet, or is now sensitive and Google was the first to add the blur.

Likely the truth will be somewhere in the middle, each of these reasons may be true some of the time, non all of the time.

I do not know about the reason for this particular blur, I always assume it has a governmental or military building where there is a blur.

No links as this is what I remember from the news back when some changes happened.